# Importing and deleting product data in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am interested in how to handle errors/exceptions/returned data correctly.

For example, I have a script which creates, updates and deletes products data.

Here is method that receives data from an API, processes and decides what to create/update/delete.

```
private function importProducts($brand)
{
    $products = $this->dsApi->getProductsByBrand($brand);

    //returns ['create' => [], 'update' => [], 'delete' => [] ]
    $preparedProducts = $this->prepareProducts($products, $brand);

    foreach ($preparedProducts['delete'] as $key => $product) {
        $this->deleteProduct($product);
        $this->log->info(
            'Brand ' . $brand->name . '(' . $brand->id_brand . ')'
            . ' id: ' . $product . ' was deleted'
        );
    }

    foreach ($preparedProducts['create'] as $key => $product) {

        $this->importProduct($product, $brand);
        $this->log->info(
            'Brand ' . $brand->name . '(' . $brand->id_brand . ') sku: ' . $product['sku'] . ' was imported'
        );
    }

    foreach ($preparedProducts['update'] as $key => $product) {
        $this->importProduct($product, $brand, $product['idProductWc']);
        $this->log->info(
            'Brand ' . $brand->name . '(' . $brand->id_brand . ') sku: ' . $product['sku']
            . ' id: ' . $product['idProductWc'] . ' was updated'
        );
    }
}
```

And for example `deleteProduct()` method:

```
private function deleteProduct($product)
{
    wp_delete_post($product, true);

    $args = [
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => (int) $product['idProductWc'],
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    ];
    $child = get_children($args);
    foreach ($child as $id => $item) {
        wp_delete_attachment($id, true);
    }
}
```

Is the deletion method written correctly? Is it necessary to handle an error in `wp_delete_post()` method? How to handle it? What to write in logs in this case? Should the method return a response?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Ludisposed I'm sorry, got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `importProducts()` method, firstly ask if this needs to be `public`, `private` or `protected` [see PHP visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Now the `importProducts()` method in question, I would separate and have three methods as follows:

```
/**
 * @param $brand string
 * @param $productsToDelete array
 */
protected function _deletePreparedProducts($brand = null, $productsToDelete = array()) {
    if(empty($brand)) {
        /* Do we need a brand? If not throw an Exception or log to your debug logger */
    }
    /* deletion logic here */
}

/**
 * @param $brand string
 * @param $productsToCreate array
 */
protected function _createPreparedProducts($brand = null, $productsToCreate = array()) { /* create logic here */ }

/**
 * @param $brand string
 * @param $productsToUpdate array
 */
protected function _updatePreparedProducts($brand = null, $productsToUpdate = array()) { /* prepare logic here */ }
```

I would therefore change the `importProducts()` method as follows (assuming that you still want this as a `private` method):

```
<?php
private function importProducts($brand)
{
    $products = $this->dsApi->getProductsByBrand($brand);

    $preparedProducts = $this->prepareProducts($products, $brand);

    if(!empty($preparedProducts['delete'])) {
        $this->_deletePreparedProducts($brand, $preparedProducts['delete']);
    }

    if(!empty($preparedProducts['create'])) {
        $this->_createPreparedProducts($brand, $preparedProducts['create']);
    }

    if(!empty($preparedProducts['update'])) {
        $this->_updatePreparedProducts($brand, $preparedProducts['update']);
    }
}
```

Using this approach, if you need to change the logic to update a product, you will only have to worry about your update method, rather than having lots of logic in one method. And in your main method you will be checking if there are any products to delete, update or create first rather than assuming that there is, as is the case in your original script.

If there are no products to import then why was this method called? This is where you could throw an exception, or log to a debug file, like this:

```
    if(empty($preparedProducts['delete'])
        && empty($preparedProducts['create'])
        && empty($preparedProducts['update'])) {
        throw new \Exception("Import products called without any products to import");
    }
```

I might also consider preparing the data first before calling the `importProducts()` method, rather than preparing that data within the method - this will depend on your dataflow.

I would finally suggest that as you are updating and deleting products, the method name may be incorrect. `manageProducts()` or something similar might be a better name for this method.

Comment: Thank you. I call `importProducts()` from another public function.. And what about `deleteProduct()`? Should I check wrong incoming data?

Comment: Yes the basic idea is to always sanitize date if you are able to first, I've thought of a way of improving my answer so I will update it presently.

Comment: Thank you. I also added another question from this project [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/how-to-handle-different-responses-from-external-api-correctly]

Comment: Updated post. I added return values to the function `deleteProducts()` and  checking it. Is it ok?

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/9717a794-3596-441f-935f-1f9450035bd4