# Wrapper class for calling external API

Tags: php, api, curl

I have a PHP cronjob script. I need to send requests and get responses from some external API.

So, there is code for the API class. In this class, I connect to the API and  call public methods of this class from another class.

```
class Api {
private $authApi;
private $logger;

function __construct()
{
    global $_AUTH_API;
    $this->authApi = $_AUTH_API;
    $this->logger = new CustomLogs();
}

public function getBrands()
{
    $options = [
        'request' => 'get_brands',
    ];

    $brands = $this->requestApi($options);

    return $brands->rows;
}

public function get****() {}

/**
 * @param $data
 *
 * @return array|mixed|object
 * @throws Exception
 */
private function requestApi($data)
{
    $data = $this->authApi + $data;

    $data = [
        'data' => json_encode($data)
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.com/api/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $answer = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    if (empty($answer)) {
        $this->logger->log->error('Empty answer from API');
        throw new Exception('Empty answer from API');
    } else {
        if ($answer->success != true) {
            $this->logger->log->error('API error: ', (array) $answer );
            throw new Exception('API error: ' . $answer->message  );
        } else {
            return $answer;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can different API responses be handled correctly? What should be written in Logs? Do I need to throw Exceptions? What should be returned to external code? (i.e. in `getBrands()`)

What would you change in this code?

Comment: what are "different API responses" actually? it's hard to answer such a question other than "handle them differently"

Comment: Sucess: true/false, empty or If API will send something unexpected.

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/182586/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's a job for at least three separate functions (that should 
belong to the different classes at best, but that would be a different story), each throwing its own exceptions.

```
protected function sendRequest($data)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($error = curl_error($ch)) {
        throw new Exception($error);
    }   
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
protected function jsonDecode($json)
{
    $data = json_decode($json);
    if (json_last_error()) {
        throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $data;
}
protected function requestApi($data)
{
    $data = $this->authApi + $data;
    $data = [
        'data' => json_encode($data)
    ];
    $response = $this->sendRequest($data);
    $answer = $this->jsonDecode($response);

    if (isset($answer->success) && $answer->success == true))) {
        return $answer;
    }
    if (isset($answer->message) {
        throw new \Exception('API error: ' . $answer->message  );
    } 
    throw new \Exception("Unknown API response: $response" );
}
```

As of the logger, I would call it in the exception handler/catch block and thus avoid repetitive calls.

Comment: Should `jsonDecode()` return `$data`? The OP [proposed that change](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/88708).

Comment: json_last_error_msg() returns "NO ERROR" and then throw Exception